# Matplotlib error occurs in JupyterNotebooks even though plot is called in a try/except block

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, try-except

I'm looping through the columns of a pandas dataframe and plotting each against a datetime column.

```
# graph all plots
if isinstance(yVar, str):
    try:
        if yVar in [col for col in boolDf.columns]:
            boolDf.plot('Date / Time', yVar, figsize=(12,3));
        else:
            numericalDf.plot('Date / Time', yVar, figsize=(12,3));
    except:
        print('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
        print('There is no data for ' + yVar + ' during this time period')
else:
    for y in yVar:
       print(y)
       try:
           if y in [col for col in boolDf.columns]:
                boolDf.plot('Date / Time', y, figsize=(12,3));
           else:
               numericalDf.plot('Date / Time', y, figsize=(12,3));
       except:
           print('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
           print('There is no data for ' + y + ' during this time period')
```

The code is plotting every figure that I want, but then gives me

```
Error in callback <function install_repl_displayhook.<locals>.post_execute at 0x0000000008A74EA0> (for post_execute):

ValueError: view limit minimum -0.001 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units
```

Why is this happening and how can I stop it?

Comment: Rather than putting the plot into a try except, make sure to only call a plot with valid data.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem. I fixed the issue by installing:

```
conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib
```

Happy coding!

Comment: My notebook already had matplotlib installed, no joy. However, my data had a NaN in it. Applying `np.isnan()` to dataset removed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was able to solve it by using: `%matplotlib inline`